# How to create an ssrs report using a wcf datasource?

Tags: wcf, reporting-services

I am trying to create a report using a wcf service as a datasource. The only somewhat definitive source of information is a [blog entry](http://weblogs.asp.net/jezell/archive/2008/02/21/using-wcf-endpoints-with-sql-reporting-services.aspx) which I am finding does not seem to work as advertised, possibly because I am using MSSQL 2008 instead of 2005.

Is it possible, and if so, how are people doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into problems as well, you have to make sure that your endpoint is using the basicHttpBinding:

```
 <endpoint address="basic"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="Secure"
              contract="IServiceContract">
```

The url in the datasource:

```
http://machinename/Service.svc/basic
```

And the query:

```
<Query><Method Namespace="schemas.xyz.com Name="MethodName" /><SoapAction>schemas.xyz.com/IServiceContract/MethodName</SoapAction></Query>
```